# Evee DoF actual Render different to rendered camera view?

Tags: rendering, camera, depth-of-field

I'm new to Blender and was wondering can anyone shed some light on the following and why this would be happening please? (apologies in advance for any improper terminology)

So, I've a rotating sphere animation and want to use to Depth of Field to create some nice bokeh blur styling for animation. In my rendered view I've set the camera to how I'd like it to look, which is showing this;

[image]

However, when I render out the image the bokeh effect appears to be not as strong?;

[image]

Any ideas why this difference would be happening? I have used DoF before and never encountered this problem until now?

Thanks

Comment: I cannot tell this for sure from the screenshots, but just a question: how large in pixels is the viewport window and how large is the rendered image? At least in the _Compositor_ with things like the _Glare_ filter and others I know that the effect varies depending on the image size.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying, I'm not sure how to get my viewport pixel size? but the output for rendering I've set to the 4K UHDTV 2160p setting.

Comment: I don't know how to get the viewport pixel size, take a screenshot and crop it to the camera window? Doesn't really matter anyway, it changes everytime you zoom in or out... but since it's most likely just a (small) portion of the whole screen it is probably a lot smaller than the rendered image... as I said, no idea if this is the problem here. Just something that might have an effect.